# Facebook OpenGraph og:url tag different than shared URL not parsed correctly

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to implement video sharing functionality in my Android app that allows the users to play the video back directly in Facebook. I'm using OpenGraph video.other type.

My problem is that the URL I want to share to FB is NOT the URL I want to put in the og:url tag. I want FB to parse the metadata from the URL I share but link the og:url in the Facebook post as the targe URL the user can go to.

When I do it that way, the FB Object debugger tries to get the metadaat from the og:url location and there are none available there.

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Example:

In Android I'm doing the following thing:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("type", "video.other");
params.putString("url", "http://mydomain.com/metadatagenerator?id=100");

Request request = new Request(
    Session.getActiveSession(),
    "me/objects/video.other",
    params,
    HttpMethod.POST
);
Response response = request.executeAndWait();
```

The link http://mydomain.com/metadatagenerator?id=100 contains this and only this:

```
<html><head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#>

<!-- START: Facebook meta data -->
<meta property = "og:type" content = "video.other"/>
<meta property = "og:video:type" content = "application/x-shockwave-flash"/>
<meta property = "og:title" content = "Test Facebook OpenGraph "/>
<meta property = "og:video:width" content = "476"/>
<meta property = "og:video" content = "https://mydomain.com/player?id=100"/>
<meta property = "og:description" content = "My test video"/>
<meta property = "og:video:height" content = "272"/>
<meta property = "og:site_name" content = "MyTestFbSiteName"/>
<meta property = "fb:app_id" content = "1234567890"/>
<meta property = "og:image" content = "http://mydomain.com/image100.jpg"/>
<meta property = "og:url" content = "http://anotherdomain.com/gohere?id=100"/>
<!-- END: Facebook meta data -->
</head>
</html>
```

I want the user to be able to go to http://anotherdomain.com/gohere?id=100 when he or she clicks the link in the FB post and I want FB to play the video located under https://mydomain.com/player?id=100 to play in the post.

Comment: I think that the best way to accomplish this is to set you web app in order to redirect the user to the wanted location when the link is clicked. Unfortunately, for what I know, the url link is both for the metadata and for redirecting link, so no way to have two different links.

Answer (score 0):

I investigated this issue further but it seems like it's not possible to do what I want. I decided to have a 'metadata provider' on my backend server to which others servers can connect and load the necessary metadata in a php script.